How to authenticate with Azure ARM API?
I have a Logic App in Azure, and I would like to create an application that will monitor all the runs and provide better filtering than the Azure Portal.
I'm trying to do a simple request to get the list of runs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflow-runs/list?view=rest-logic-2016-06-01&tabs=HTTP
But the API endpoint requires an authentication token, and the problem is I don't know how to get it, there aren't any details about how to get it.
Is there a step-by-step guide anywhere of how to do this? I've done a little research, and every link I found is outdated with details about pages in the Azure Portal that are different than years ago.

Any update on the issue?

To generate the access token and call the Azure Service Management API, you need to create a Microsoft Entra ID application and add the below API permission:

Assign Logic App Contributor, Logic App Operator or Reader role to the application:

Now generate the access token by passing parameters like below:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=ClientID
scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
client_secret=ClientSecret
grant_type=client_credentials


I created the workflow the sample workflow using this API call mentioned in the MsDoc that is consumption logic app.
I am able to successfully fetch the Workflow Runs by passing the access token:

Note that: The below API works only for consumption logic app not for standard.

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs?api-version=2016-06-01


For Standard Logic app, you need to assign Reader role to the application:

And make use of the below API to list the runs:
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/RGName/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/rukla/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/WorkFlowName/runs?api-version=2018-11-01


Refer this Microsoft QnA by MayankBargali-MSFTto check the APIs for Standard logic app.
You can also make use of user interactive flows to call the APIs.
Reference:
OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow on the Microsoft identity platform - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft
